# Deploying Azure Functions through Maven Plugin

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app

I am trying to deploy a Java based Azure Function App through IntelliJ IDEA as mentioned `[here][1]`. I am using the Maven goals for the deployment with the following settings in my POM file.

```
<groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <appName>Name of the function app</appName>
            <resourceGroup>Resource Group</resourceGroup>
            <appServicePlanName>App Service Plan Name</appServicePlanName>
```

When I deploy the Azure function app using mvn azure-functions:deploy the deployments go through successfully as mentioned by the deployment logs. However when I log in to the Azure Portal I do not see the functions.
I have tried deploying them through VS Code and the deployment is successful. I want to make it working from Maven because that is the preferable deployment automation pattern for us.
Is there any suggestions on what I can investigate further? I am sure I am missing something fundamental here.
Prabal Rakshit
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/toolkit-for-intellij/quickstart-functions

Comment: Did you login your azure account in IDEA ?

Comment: Yes. Did indeed log on to the Azure account in IDEA

Comment: Did you figure this out?